# JMeter tests are failing when running with multiple iterations

Tags: jmeter

I recently started using jmeter and created my test cases under the thread group. When I run then with single user or iteration the test pass. But when I ran like 5 iterations. then 2 to 3 tests are failed. Not sure what I am missing here.
jmeter version 5.4.1
The host for the testcases are running on API, not on regular website
ex. peregrine-api-${ENV}-raven.ocp-nonprod.com

Please find the screenshots of my jmeter test setup and let me know if you need any other information

Test plan tree

[image: Test plan tree]

Testcase settings

[image: Test case settings]

Results table

[[image: Results table3]

This is the response I am getting for few iterations and few runs are executing successfully

```
{
    "message": "An error has taken place",
    "errors": [
        "An error has taken place"
    ],
    "status": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

0. `INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR` is a [**SERVER** error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500), for well-behaved servers it means that there is nothing wrong with the JMeter request, it's server who cannot properly handle the request so it worth checking server logs and look for the reason there
1. Use [View Results Tree](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener and compare the request which is successful with the one which fails. If you're using JMeter Properties and/or Variables - the values can be visualized using [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script)
2. Any reason for using 2 different [Thread Groups?](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) If `Create Mailbox` request requires authentication it makes more sense to keep keycload auth and requests which require authentication under the same Thread Group
3. According to JMeter Best Practices [you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so it worth considering migrating to [JMeter 5.4.3](https://lists.apache.org/thread/dbg1bxywcwx5vtdwqf8ownf7ppgqjn41) or whatever is the latest stable version which is available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T, 0. I checked with my team and it seems the issue was with the server as when I try to create the mailbox on the web, its working fine and with API its throwing the error. 2. When I use multiple flows in multiple threads as some test cases are dependent on other ones from other threads, I want to avoid the keycloak auth repetition and so I thought of using in separate thread. Correct me if there is some other better way to do this. Question, can I use same user for multiple iterations like 1000 with ramp up time as 5 secs in 1 loop?